# PDO Mysql create function and use in select

Tags: mysql, pdo, fatal-error

I want to create a MySQL function in my PDO setup.

```
$connection->exec('
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS return_id
CREATE FUNCTION return_id(id int(11)) RETURN int(11)
BEGIN
return id;
END');

$fetch=$connection->query('select *,return_id(id) as new_id from category')->fetchall();
print_r($fetch);
```

I am getting the error:

```
FATAL ERROR: UNCAUGHT ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION FETCHALL() ON BOOLEAN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here. Firstly, you're not checking the return status of your `$connection->exec` call which will be false because you have syntax errors, a missing `;` at the end of the first line i.e. it should be

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS return_id;
```

However, PDO::exec will not execute multiple statements, so you need to put the function definition into a separate `exec` anyway.

Next: `RETURN` should be `RETURNS`

Finally, you're not checking the result of the call to `$connection->query` which is also returning `false` (the boolean which does not have a member function fetchAll) because it failed due to the previous errors.

To make it work you need to change your code to this. However you should as best practice also check the results of the calls to `$connection->exec` and `$connection->query`.

```
$connection->exec('DROP function IF EXISTS return_id');
$connection->exec('CREATE FUNCTION return_id(id int(11)) RETURNS int(11) BEGIN return id; END');
$fetch=$connection->query('select *,return_id(id) as new_id from category')->fetchall();
print_r($fetch);
```